# Programmatically Enable Location Service in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, geolocation

Is that possible by any means for iOS devices (be it the JailBroken way) to toggle Location service in programmatic way? In my use case, user should be able to switch on Location service (to or or off) using the code, rather than manually going to settings & changing it.

Comment: In the official SDK this is not possible. On a jailbroke device this should be possible.

Comment: @rckoenes : Can you elaborate "On a jailbroke device this should be possible" with few supporting code ?

Comment: no I can not since I do not develop for jailbroke devices. But that are app on Cydia which allow you to toggle the location service so it should be possible.

Comment: In _enableAccessibility method https://github.com/square/KIF/blob/master/Classes/KIFTestController.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use private APIs. If you distribute, your app will be rejected by the app store.

Comment: Do you have an example for such a private API? I cannot find one on my own unfortunately and the link you shared above in the comments leads to a 404.